# Remove NaN and Inf values for series with belonging series

Tags: python, pandas

I have prediction and actual values, which look like:

```
409   -9938.1580
410   -9938.1580
411   -9938.1580
412   -9938.1580
413   -9938.1580
414   -9938.1580
415   NaN
416   -9703.9345
Name: actuals, dtype: float64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>


409   NaN
410   -9938.1580
411   -9938.1580
412   -9944.1580
413   -9938.1580
414   -9000.1580
415   -1000.0000
416   -9903.9345
Name: predictions, dtype: float64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

My problem is, that this values can contain `NaN`or `Inf` numbers, which lead to an error in a lot of `sklearn.metrics`, for example in the method:

```
import sklearn.metrics
mean_squared_error(actuals, predictions)
```

it leads to the error:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN.

I know this error occurs, because I have `NaN` or `Inf` inside, how can I automatically remove the `NaN and Inf` numbers from both series with the belonging entry of the other series?

So in my case the series would look like:

```
410   -9938.1580
411   -9938.1580
412   -9938.1580
413   -9938.1580
414   -9938.1580
416   -9703.9345
Name: actuals, dtype: float64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>



410   -9938.1580
411   -9938.1580
412   -9944.1580
413   -9938.1580
414   -9000.1580
416   -9903.9345
Name: predictions, dtype: float64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: Are those columns in a dataframe or just separate lists?

Comment: it is a seperated list

Comment: I just changed the series name to "actual" for clarity. Although it's possible that both series have the same name, it doesn't matter here and using a different name will be more explicit to figure readers. Feel free to revert if you disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify the common non-NA indices and only use those:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

keep = actuals.index[actuals.notna()].intersection(predictions.index[predictions.notna()])

mean_squared_error(actuals[keep], predictions[keep])
# 153313.33333333334
```

Another and more generic option would be to use a DataFrame to transparently align the Series and [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to remove the NaNs in all columns at once:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({'actuals': actuals, 'predictions': predictions})
        .replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
        .dropna()
     )

mean_squared_error(df['actuals'], df['predictions'])
# 153313.33333333334
```

Comment: for `Inf` its the same way?

Comment: Oops, I forgot this case, not you need to handle `Inf`  separately. Either using [`numpy.isfinite`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isfinite.html) in combination with `notna`, or maybe more conveniently, replacing infinite values by NaN and using a single `dropna`.

Comment: unfortunalety it gives the error: ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0,)) while a minimum of 1 is required.

Comment: I tried to add if len(predictions)>0 but this does not work

Comment: Can you check that `df` is not empty?

Comment: works now, with an if-condition